# Sites for seeking possible collaborations

Tags: soft-question, physics

As a material scientist, I have recently constructed algorithms for solving ground state of arbitrary cluster interactions models and prepared publications in the field of physics and material science. Indeed, I wish to further develop my theory (either in algorithm sense or even construct a brand new representation in terms of groups) in mathematical aspect and I am wondering whether there might be some sites that I could look for possible collaborations with mathematician. Thank you:)

Comment: I don't think there are such websites; finding collaboration is done by email or telephone, based on contact information. However, may this not be (?!) a subject for a stackexchange website (if you think so, I suggest going to stackexchange Area 51->submit proposal). Users suggest a topic (and supply prior published work) and users interested in collaboration can post an "answer" with a link to some of their work. People judge who are best fits by voting. If collaboration occurs, answer "accepted"? (Just throwing the idea out there.) I can't suggest more not knowing what your papers are about.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "sites"? I would suggest looking at mathematicians working on related fields, and emailing. Alternately, you can cross-post your arXiv.org papers to the appropriate math fields. Maybe then they will email you :)

Comment: Actually, I mean websites or forums:) Sorry for my ignorance, usually people in material science (at least in our group) don't quite publish papers in archive, and where shall I make the posting? Thank you:)

Comment: @user40780 Since I don't know what your papers are about, exactly, it is hard to recommend specific areas...